Error con ODBC [01000][UnixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmaodbc.so' : file not found
os comento un error que no se como solucionarlo, os explico la situación.
En clase (En sistemas gestor de base de datos) tenemos una tarea la cual tenemos que conectarnos mediante ODBC de una máquina virtual a la otra que tiene la base de datos de MariaDB, al parecer, la idea es que nos diese un error el cual no pudiesemos conectarnos ya que haria falta activar o configurar algo, pero curiosamente, a mi me ha dado un error distinto que es el que expongo en el título, cuando hagoisql -v ODBCMariaDBMe salta el siguiente fallo
[01000][UnixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmaodbc.so' : file not found
El caso es que no encuentra el archivo pese a estar ahí ya que se copio previamente antes de realizar incluso los .ini, os dejo como esta configurada la cosa
Servidor: 192.168.100.5 (MariaDB y ODBC) 
Cliente: 192.168.100.10 (ODBC)
Si hago ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/ esta libmaodbc.so en la carpeta, tiene de usuario y grupo de root, y le di permisos de 755 para que lo pudieran leer aquellos que no fueran root por si acaso fuese el problema, aunque no se solucionó.
mire la configuración y creo que esta correcta, esta de esta manera en el cliente:
/etc/odbcinst.ini
[MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver]
Description=MariaDB Connector/ODBC v.3.0
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmaodbc.so
UsageCount=1

/etc/odbc.ini
[ODBCMariaDB]
Description = MariaDB Server
Driver = MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver
Server = 192.168.100.5
User = XXXXXXXX
Password = XXXXXXXX
Database = Prueba
Port = 3306

El usuario y contraseña dentro de XXXXX es uno que he creado desde MariaDB 'usuario'@'192.168.100.10' en el servidor.
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'192.168.100.10' IDENTIFIED BY 'usuario' WITH GRANT OPTIONS; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
En el servidor, la configuración de odbc.ini y odbcinst.ini están de manera parecida, lo único que cambia es que el odbc.ini esta haciendo objetivo al usuario administrador en el servidor localhost, por lo demás esta todo igual, y en el servidor se puede conectar mediante isql.
EDIT: finalmente se consiguio arreglar, el fallo estuvo por una dependencia (lo dejo expuesto por si a alguien le sucediese, usando el comando ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmaodbc.so | grep -E "not found$" dejaba expuesto que faltaba una libreria
    libmariadb.so.3 => not found

Entonces buscando información sobre dicha libreria, en la página oficial de mariadb encontré los repositorios que habia que instalar
sudo apt install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev

Instale ambos y ya habia desaparecido la instancia que no encontraba, y ya podía intentar conectarme, aunque fallaba con un error nuevo, el S1000
[S1000][UnixODBC][ma-3.2.3]Can't connect to server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (115)
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

La solución que tome tras esto fue configurar el /etc/mysql/my.cnf del ubuntu que hacia de servidor y le agregue un par de lineas:
#skip-networking
bind-address = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (IP del servidor)

y luego habilite el puerto 3306 en el servidor para las conexiones
sudo ufw allow 3306

Y finalmente ya pude conectarme con isql, todo era por la falta de dependencias que revelo el comando ldd, lo expongo por si alguien le sucede pueda guiarse por lo que me paso y probar los pasos que hice.
Muchas gracias de antemano y saludos ^^

Lo consegui arreglar, dejo los pasos que realice para conseguir conectarme y así pueda servirle a alguien que pase por el mismo problema en las configuraciones ^^.
